# Writing Tasklet in Spring Batch

Tags: java, xml, spring, batch-processing

I am writing the data retrieved from the database in a .txt file in a particular format. I need to put 0s before a particular field retrieved.

For Example: If the value of a column retrieved from the database is 123, I need to make it as 5 digits and the number should be preceded by 2 zeros. i.e. "00123".

For a number like 2, it should be "00002"

But instead of 0s I need space. I am unable to figure it out.

The .xml code that I use for it is

```
<bean id="neiertzItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter">
    <property name="resource" value="${renewalNeiertzData}" />
    <property name="lineAggregator">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.FormatterLineAggregator">
            <property name="fieldExtractor">
                <bean
                    class="com.accord.batch.neiertz.tasklet.FormattingBeanWrapperFieldExtractor">
                    <property name="names"
                        value="contractNumber,engagementNumber,creationDate,commercantNumber,productCode,externalReference" />
                    <property name="dateFormatting">
                        <map key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="java.lang.String">
                            <entry key="creationDate" value="yyyyMMdd" />
                        </map>
                    </property>
                    <property name="numberFormatting">
                        <map key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="java.lang.String">
                            <entry key="contractNumber" value="%015d" />
                            <entry key="engagementNumber" value="%011d" />
                            <entry key="commercantNumber" value="%09d" />
                            <entry key="productCode" value="%05d" />
                            <entry key="externalReference" value="%030d" />
                        </map>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="format" value="%-15s%-11s%-8s%-9s%-5s%-30s" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

How Do I change to make it for white spaces instead of zeros. I don't understand the equivalent for space in java and how to put it in xml.

Comment: Are you saying that you don't actually need any of the 0's at all for any numbers?

Comment: I am saying I need 0s for some fields and for some I need spaces instead of zeros.